# Does Rocksdb support any mechanism/API to export the saved records in text file like JSON or CSV?

Tags: rocksdb

I want to use RocksDB as a storage. I want to export the database to human redable format like Json or CSV. Does Rocksdb support that ? If yes,  it also possible to import the data back in database ?

Comment: Rocksdb is a key-value store from what I know very similar to Leveldb. You should be able to retrieve the data by opening Rocksdb database and retrieving all key and value pairs programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Not natively, no, but it would be easy to write something using an Iterator scan. You can also query the DB in human readable form using the `ldb` tool. https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Administration-and-Data-Access-Tool